# How to find out all integers between two real numbers using R

Tags: r, integer

Problem: how can I write a function that receives `a` and `b` as inputs and returns all integers inbetween them. So, assuming we have a function called `integers_inbetween` that behaves like this, we should expect the following examples:

```
# Returns an array of integers in between a and b
integers_inbetween(1, 4)
[1] 2 3
```

and

```
# Returns an array of integers in between a and b
integers_inbetween(4, 1)
[1] 2 3
```

And

```
# Returns NULL if there are no integers inbetween a and b
integers_inbetween(3.5, 4)
[1] NULL
```

How can one implement that logic in R?

Comment: can you accept the best answer?

Answer (score 3):

This solution should work. I'm assuming the function should work if `a > b` and also if not. The way I wrote it, if after rounded `a == b`, the function returns `NULL`.

```
inbetween_integers <- function(a, b) {
    a <- round(a)
    b <- round(b)
    dist_ab <- abs(a-b)
    if (dist_ab <= 1)
        return(NULL)
    if (b < a)
        return(seq.int(from = b + 1, length.out = dist_ab - 1))
    return(seq.int(from = a + 1, length.out = dist_ab - 1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
inbetween_integers <- function(a, b) {
  u <- sort(c(a, b))
  res <- setdiff(ceiling(u[1]):floor(u[2]), c(a, b))
  if (!length(res)) {
    NULL
  } else {
    res
  }
}
```

and you will see

```
> inbetween_integers(1, 4)
[1] 2 3

> inbetween_integers(4, 1)
[1] 2 3

> inbetween_integers(3.5, 4)
NULL
```

Comment: Suggestion: using `if /  else` as you did is not useful. There are only two possible outcomes, so you could just: `if (!length(res)) return(NULL)` and right after it `return(res)`

Comment: @eduardokapp yes, exactly, we can do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

This works regardless of the order of arguments.
First this function sorts the arguments, then determines the minimum and maximum values in the sequence (exclusive of integer boundaries), then returns the sequence as requested.

```
integers_in_between<-function(x,y){
        values<-sort(c(x,y))
        minimum<-ifelse(ceiling(values[1])==values[1], ceiling(values[1])+1, ceiling(values[1]))
        maximum<-ifelse(floor(values[2])==values[2], floor(values[2])-1, floor(values[2]))
        if(maximum-minimum<0){
                NULL
        }else{
                minimum:maximum
        }
}
```